# What are the risks of running VS2010 side by side with VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Officially, it's supported. I get that. I've personally done it in a VM. My question is, are there any hidden gotchas of running VS2012.x side by side with VS2010 SP'd and hotfix'd? I recall reading about an issue with the version of .NET or the CLR, I don't recall the details and it was last fall.

My coworkers and I would really like to move to 2012 but we have a lead developer that refuses to move. We need to convince him, especially since we have a large project that was started on 3.5, moved to 4.0 (will not go to 4.5), but we've heard rumblings about the aforementioned *possible* problem.

Comment: This is rather open ended and as such not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place update. This means that once you install it all apps (including VS 2010) will be running against .NET Framework 4.5 and not .NET Framework 4. While there has been a great effort to make .NET Framework 4.5 backwards compatible there are some (mostly minor) bugs where the behavior changed in .NET Framework 4. 
I think the biggest thing you should consider is whether you are going to target .NET Framework 4 in your apps. The problem is that when you target .NET Framework 4 your VS2012 will only allow you to use APIs that as they were in .NET Framework 4 **but** your app will actually run using .NET Framework 4.5 runtime. I have seen cases where a legitimate bug in .NET Framework 4.5 was fixed (i.e. an incorrect exception is no longer thrown) but when you run your app against real .NET Framework 4 the app did not work even though it targeted .NET Framework 4 because the bug is still there. Note that you can get to the same situation even with VS 2010 if you install .NET Framework 4.5 on your box. I have been running both SxS and I have not had any problems (but am primarily using VS2012 - is so much faster and more stable). 
I think the main take aways here are

- if you are working on .NET Framework 4 make sure you test your app on real .NET Framework 4
- try running VS2012 sxs with VS2010 on a limited set of machines and if you don't see any problem move on
- you may also try running VS2012 only if you don't use any functionality that is not supported in VS2012 (the biggest risk in this case is the .NET Framework anyway and running VS2010 only will not protect you anyways)